# How to initialize a NSDocument after calling LSLaunchFSRefSpec?

Tags: c++, macos, nsdocument, launch-services, nsapplication-delegate

I am working on a document-based application. If I execute this app from the Finder it runs like expected: First the `NSApplicationDelegate` `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method is executed. Then the `NSPersistentDocument` initialization is done. After that the defined `NSDocument` `makeWindowControllers` method is executed, which creates the window controllers from the `WindowNibName`'s.

In case of using the Finder everything works fine and the app launches like expected. But if I will execute the document-based application from another application using `LSLaunchFSRefSpec` from the Launch Service Reference, the app is just shown inside the Dock. No window appears. No `NSPersistentDocument` will be initialized and no `makeWindowControllers` method will be executed. Only the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method is called.
At the moment the initialization and the creation of the window controllers could just be done if I activate the app from dock by one mouse click. I also tested different launch flags for the `LSLaunchFSRefSpec`, without any success.

Is it possible to activate the app and create their windows automatically? Or maybe I can simulate a mouse click on the dock icon?